# Opening Content Editor taking too long time to load

Tags: configuration, content-editor, caching

I have configured an environment for Sitecore XP 8.2.7 and it seems it is not somehow using cache properly when opening Content Editor since it takes just too long time for the initial loading.

What could be the possible cause for this? Settings were wrong?
Any thoughts?

Comment: Check how many entries you have in each database (core, master, web) in the following tables: History, EvenntQueue, PublishQueue. Document the number of records then purge these tables.

Comment: Is it slow every time you load the Content Editor, or only the first time the application comes up after being updated?

Comment: From my experience an issue with Sitecore Connecting to MongoDb can typically cause performance issues.  The best way to know if that's the culprit is to check your Data\logs, and look for the most recent txt file with logs as a prefix on it.  If you go down near the bottom or do a search for "Mongo" and you see issues related to connection, than this is likely the issue.  The answer below shows how to disable xDb which in turn will disable Mongo, but you shouldn't disable xDb, because you probably need it. Fix the underlying Mongo issue instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check from the browser console logs for any errors and access deny and Sitecore `Data/logs/log.txt` file for more info?

Also, are you using Xdb? If not then you should set the properties `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` as false in `Sitecore.Xdb.config` (please see screenshot).

[image]

Please let me know if you have more info on this.